# Image doesn't display after changing src attribute

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Like the title says after I change the `src` to the value during the `rollEvent` function, the image doesn't change.  When I print the value of `display.src` to console it is correct.  But the actual document doesn't change the `src` value for the `img` tag with the class of display_box.  Am I missing something here?

[jsfiddle.net/bNL5C/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/bNL5C/3/)

```
window.onload = function eventsLoad (elem, display) {
    elem = document.getElementsByClassName('images');
    display = document.getElementsByClassName('display_box');
    function rollEvent(e) {
        var sourceURL = this.src;
        console.log(sourceURL);
        display.src = sourceURL;
        console.log(display.src);
    };
    console.log(elem);
    console.log(display);
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        elem[i].addEventListener('mouseover', rollEvent, false);
        console.log('Added event listener to ' + elem[i]);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns NodeList, so you should change `display.src = sourceURL`:

```
function rollEvent(e) {
    var sourceURL = this.src;
    display[0].src = sourceURL; // <--- change here
    console.log(display.src);
};
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bNL5C/4/

or use `display = document.querySelector('.display_box');` instead.

Comment: So simple! Thank you, completely overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... Change:

```
document.getElementsByClassName returns an array - display is a list. Try changing
    display.src = sourceURL;
```

To:

```
display[0].src = sourceURL;
```